# bazel rules_nodejs can't be deployed using rules_k8s: wrong platform

Tags: node.js, bazel

I'm building a nodejs app from OSX and trying to deploy it to kubernetes using `rules_k8s`.

It almost works, except that the node doesn't start because of this error:

```
/app/examples/hellohttp/nodejs/nodejs-hellohttp_image.binary: line 147: /app/examples/hellohttp/nodejs/nodejs-hellohttp_image.binary.runfiles/com_github_yourbase_yourbase/external/nodejs/bin/node: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/app/examples/hellohttp/nodejs/nodejs-hellohttp_image.binary: line 147: /app/examples/hellohttp/nodejs/nodejs-hellohttp_image.binary.runfiles/com_github_yourbase_yourbase/external/nodejs/bin/node: Success
```

It looks like the `node` binary being deployed wasn't built for the right platform where k8s is running (linux with amd64, normal Google GKE nodes).

The command I'm using to make the deployment:

`bazel run --cpu=k8 //examples/hellohttp/nodejs:nodejs-hellohttp_deploy.apply`

I tried with other combinations of `--platforms` or `--cpu` but I couldn't get it to work.

The argument that felt like the closest was this:

```
$ bazel run --platforms=@bazel_tools//platforms:linux //examples/hellohttp/nodejs:nodejs-hellohttp_deploy.apply
ERROR: While resolving toolchains for target //examples/hellohttp/nodejs:nodejs-hellohttp_deploy.apply: Target constraint_value rule @bazel_tools//platforms:linux was found as the target platform, but does not provide PlatformInfo
ERROR: Analysis of target '//examples/hellohttp/nodejs:nodejs-hellohttp_deploy.apply' failed; build aborted: Target constraint_value rule @bazel_tools//platforms:linux was found as the target platform, but does not provide PlatformInfo
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.255s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
ERROR: Build failed. Not running target
```

This says there was a toolchain problem, and says something about missing PlatformInfo, but it doesn't say anything about how do I fix it. :-(

For what is worth, with Go I had similar problems, and they were solved by passing `--experimental_platforms=@io_bazel_rules_go//go/toolchain:linux_amd64` to the bazel run command.

How do I make something similar work for nodejs?

Comment: I have effectively the same problem, except for Python.